# Showing df.info(), df.head(), df.shape, df.dtypes in one step

Tags: python, dataframe

when using Jupyter Notebook, I have to make separate spaces for `df.info()`, `df.head()`, etc. mentioned in the title of the question.

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

Is there a way to put all of these in one block like in 2nd picture, and showing all the information
[image: Jupyter Notebook]

Comment: df.info(),df.head(),df.shape,df.dtypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a comma on the same line

```
df.info(), df.head(), df.shape, df.dtypes
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option is use `display`

```
display(df.info())
display(df.head())
display(df.shape())
```

Depending on the version of jupyter, you may have to do the import `from IPython.display import display`

Another advantage of `display` is in case of printing multiple dataframes. The output would be same as if you have printed one df, which is not in the case of using `,`

Answer (score -1):

you can put them in a same line or in separate lines. but it will still give the same results.

put them in same line using commas:

```
df.info(), df.head(), df.head(), df.dtypes
```

Comment: OP already tried separate lines and that didn't work. Maybe you mean separate lines with commas?